# How to customize the Checkout page In Magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2.4.6

My checkout page does not look good, it looks like the LUMA checkout page,

I want to restyle the checkout page, give my own CSS, and make it one page checkout,

How can I do that?

I am learning Magento, can you also share any developer guide?

Answer (score 0):

Use can user third-party Extension/Module to the one step checkout.

Please check below links for your need or check demo.

https://www.magetop.com/magento-2-one-step-checkout-extension.html

https://store.webkul.com/magento2-one-step-checkout.html

https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-one-step-checkout-extension.html

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-one-step-checkout-extension/